# Cannot access recorded media for upload

Tags: android, cordova, media, record

I created a hybrid application with Cordova/Phonegap. I used Media API for recording audio file and I want to upload it to a server with post method.

upload process is ok if I use audio files inside the application.
media record creates audio files in root of filesystem(like emulated/0/ in Android)

if I use LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY it creates inside the cache folder but when I want to play it inside the app it gives me an error

I need the URI of recorded file to use for FileUpload
or Give me a working solution
thanks

```
    var app = {
    onRecordButton: function() {
    var src = "statement.wav";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src, app.onSuccess2, app.onError2);

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();

    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 10;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime - 1;
        app.setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
        if (recTime <= 0) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            mediaRec.stopRecord();
        }
    }, 1000);
},

    CompleteButton: function(){
    var audioURI = "statement.wav";
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
   options.fileKey="file";
   options.fileName="statement.wav";
   options.mimeType="audio/wav";

   var params = new Object();
   params.key = value;
    options.params = params;

   var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(audioURI, encodeURI(url), app.win, app.fail, options);
   },

    }
```